# For some reason the DriveSpace Attribute in the script always returns empty. Cannot seem to find the issue

Tags: powershell

Trying to make a list of computers and their specs on our domain for list i need to prepare. Ive been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong but cant come up with anything. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter * |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
          Foreach($computer in $computers){
    if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
         {write-host "cannot reach $computer offline" -f red}
          else {
    $outtbl = @()
    Try{
    $sr=Get-WmiObject win32_bios -ComputerName $Computer  -ErrorAction Stop 
    $Xr=Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop   
    $ld=get-adcomputer $computer -properties Name,Lastlogondate,operatingsystem,ipv4Address,enabled,description,DistinguishedName -ErrorAction Stop
    $r="{0} GB" -f ((Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $computer |Measure-Object Capacity  -Sum).Sum / 1GB)
    $s="{0} GB" -f (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computer | ? {$_. DriveType -eq 3} | select DeviceID, {$_.Size /1GB}, {$_.FreeSpace /1GB})
    $x = gwmi win32_computersystem -ComputerName $computer |select Manufacturer,@{Name = "Model";Expression = {if (($_.model -eq "$null")  ) {'Virtual'} Else {$_.model}}},username -ErrorAction Stop
    $t= New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        computername = $ld.name
        Ipaddress=$ld.ipv4Address
        Enabled=$ld.Enabled
        Description=$ld.description
        Ou=$ld.DistinguishedName.split(',')[1].split('=')[1] 
        Ram=$R
        DriveSize=($s.Size | Out-String).Trim()
        ProcessorName=($xr.name | Out-String).Trim()
        NumberOfCores=($xr.NumberOfCores | Out-String).Trim()
        NumberOfLogicalProcessors=($xr.NumberOfLogicalProcessors | Out-String).Trim()
        Operatingsystem=$ld.operatingsystem
        Lastlogondate=$ld.lastlogondate
        LoggedinUser=$x.username
        }
        $outtbl += $t
        }
        catch [Exception]
        {
            "Error communicating with $computer, skipping to next"   
        }
       $outtbl | select Computername,enabled,description,ipAddress,Ou,Ram,DriveSize,ProcessorName,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors,Operatingsystem,loggedinuser,Lastlogondate |export-csv -Append -Force
```

Comment: Yeah, you're referencing a property that doesn't exist since your *stringifying* it using the `-f` operator. Is there any reason why you're not using the newer *CIM* cmdlets?

Comment: i see that you have the problem identified and a solution ... so this is FYI -- [1] using 1-letter var names is almost always a bad idea [other than as an index holder. use _meaningful_ var names. ///// [2] you are making MANY calls across your net to each system. if you use the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet, you can send a scriptblock to each system and run the whole set of calls on the remote systems - in parallel. [*grin*] for an example, lookee ... >>> basic remote parallel SystemInfo demo script - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/cGL5biWH <<<